# How to use JWT token to authorize user from react to asp net core web api. When to use autorization header bearer token?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, react-hooks

Im building React app with Asp net core Web Api. I implemented JWT authorization where I store jwt token in local storage. Do I need to send it with every request to my webapi with Authorization header 'Bearer'? And do I need to check the token in headers every time in my backend? I want my user to be authorized when making request but I dont know how to it.

This is my JwtService

```
public class JWTAuthService
    {
        private readonly JwtTokenConfig jwtTokenConfig;
        private readonly ILogger<JWTAuthService> logger;

        public JWTAuthService(
            JwtTokenConfig jwtTokenConfig,
            ILogger<JWTAuthService> logger)
        {
            this.jwtTokenConfig = jwtTokenConfig;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public string BuildToken(Claim[] claims)
        {
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.jwtTokenConfig.Secret));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: this.jwtTokenConfig.Issuer,
                    audience: this.jwtTokenConfig.Audience,
                    notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(this.jwtTokenConfig.AccessTokenExpiration),
                    signingCredentials: creds);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }

        public string BuildRefreshToken()
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[32];
            using var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
        }

        public ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipalFromToken(string token)
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenValidator = new();
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.jwtTokenConfig.Secret));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = key,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
            };

            try
            {
                var principal = tokenValidator.ValidateToken(token, parameters, out var securityToken);

                if (!(securityToken is JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken) || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    this.logger.LogError($"Token validation failed");
                    return null;
                }

                return principal;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.logger.LogError($"Token validation failed: {e.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my auth where I return the user Id

```
 [HttpPost("user")]
        public string UserAuth([FromBody] string accessToken)
        {
            
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = this.jwtAuthService.GetPrincipalFromToken(accessToken);
            string id = claimsPrincipal.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "id").Value;

           var userId = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id);
            return userId;

        }
```

This is my login component in react

```
const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const user = {
            username,
            password,
        };
        
        await fetch('https://localhost:44366/api/AppUsers/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(res => {

            if (res.AccessToken) {
                localStorage.setItem("jwt", res.AccessToken);
            }
        })

        setRedirect(true);
    }

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />
    }

here is return state
```

I have posts on my home page where user can submit comments. I need userId to make the post request to my Api. First Im doing one request for getting the userId and then to post the comment.I know thats not the way and I need some help on how to do it.

```
const Card = (props) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState();

  const {
    postId,
    key,
    profilePicture,
    image,
    comments,
    likedByText,
    likedByNumber,
    hours,
    content,
    title,
    accountName,
  } = props;

  const submitComment = (e, postId) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    const fetchUrl = `https://localhost:44366/api/AppUsers/user`;

    const fetchData = () => {
      fetch((fetchUrl),
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(jwt),
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => setUserId(result))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };

    fetchData();

    const id = postId;
    const data = {
      Content: text,
      UserId: userId,
      PostId: id ,
    }

    fetch('https://localhost:44366/api/Comments/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });

    setText('');
  }
  return (
    <div className="card" key={id}>
      <header>
        <Profile iconSize="big" image={profilePicture} accountName={accountName} />
      </header>
      <p className='text-center'>{title}</p>
      <p className='text-center'>  {content}</p>
      <ImageSlider slides={image} />

      <CardMenu />
      <div className="likedBy">
        <Profile iconSize="small" image={profilePicture} />
        <span>
          Liked by <strong>{likedByText}</strong> and{" "}
          <strong>{comments.Lenght} 50 others</strong>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className="comments">
        {comments?.slice(0, 5).map((comment) => (

          <Comment
            key={comment.id}
            accountName={comment.User.FirstName ? comment.User.FirstName : null}
            comment={comment.Content}
          />
        )
        )}

        {showMore && comments?.slice(5).map((comment) => (
          <Comment
            key={comment.id}
            accountName={comment.User.FirstName ? comment.User.FirstName : null}
            comment={comment.Content}
          />
        ))}

        <button type="button" className="button" onClick={() => setShowMore(true)}>Show more comments</button>
      </div>
      
      <div className="timePosted">Before {hours} hours.</div>
      <form data={postId} onSubmit={e => submitComment(e, id)}>
        <div className="addComment">
          <textarea type="text" value={text} placeholder="Напишете коментар" className="commentText" onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
          <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  >Post</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add Authorization header 'Bearer' you can also create yourself a custom header and send the token there.

now in the backend you put a middleware that check the token before you reach it.

in the auth I personally use axios and you can configure there an api that auto insert the Header

Comment: Can you tell me more about that middleware ? Do I need to check the token if its valid or I need to check only if there is that token in request and accept that user is authorized?

Comment: i more of a nodejs developer but it should be similar you check first if you got authorization and then check if the token is valid when  its valid 
you can  forward the payload so you can use the data for different stuff like id of the user